# Creating Job Tickets

Tags: database, forms

I work in a small print shop and I want to digitize our workflow. 
I have found many plugins that are for support tickets, but I want to be able to create job tickets for printing jobs. I have found several of form plugins (Gravity, Formidable Pro) that make the form portion easy, but I need a way to create reports and view the data that is being stored in the db. I need the ability to create relational databases. Is this possible within wordpress?

Comment: As in custom databases, or you want to use...say, a custom post type within the current database strucutre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  WordPress uses a relational database and you're free to add tables to it.   As a warning - you will need to create new functions/classes to work with your new tables.  WordPress' built in functions will probably not work with new tables.

As a side note, new content types such as reports and tickets can be encapsulated in Custom Post Types.  With CPTs you have built in WordPress functions at your disposal and it's easy to create an admin section for your new CPT.

I've done both, adding custom tables and using CPTs for new content types.  I find using CPTs a lot more convenient and productive most of the time.

Comment: You can use the [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class for interacting with custom tables.